# \ in path.combine in c#

Tags: c#, path

I know this is asked many times, but I couldn't exactly find what I need.

I want to get the server path and add image path to that. I did that

```
string mypath = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
string uploadPath = Path.Combine(mypath, "Upload/Images/");
Response.Write(uploadPath);
```

This printed `http://localhost\Upload/Images/`, why is there a `\` in the middle of the path.

I fixed it by adding `/` to `mypath` like this

```
string mypath = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/";
```

Is this the correct way? or is there is any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `Path.Combine` is meant to combine typical directory path, something like:

```
C:\MyDir\MyDir2\MyMyDir
```

where the separator is `\`, not URL where the separator is `/`:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249357/in-path-combine-in-c-sharp/37249373#37249373
```

If you want to combine URL path, you could use `Uri` instead:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri(mypath);
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "Upload/Images/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class for URLs, as `Path.Combine` is used for directory path operations.

> Provides an object representation of a uniform resource identifier (URI) and easy access to the parts of the URI.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri(mypath);
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "Upload/Images/");
string uploadPath = myUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

And to get the URL, [AbsoluteUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri(v=vs.110).aspx) property can be used.